# Best music playlist generator software

Tags: music, playlists

Does anyone know of a playlist generator that will generate a .m3u file from a folder full of .mp3 files?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since m3u is basically just a list of files you can use dir command like this:

> dir /b > songlist.m3u

This will make a list of files in a folder. If you also want to add files in all sub folders, add switch /s, however this will add full path in front of files so if the songs are on a portable player you might want to edit out the path to original folder.

If you have other files in folders and only want to add mp3 files, you can use filter *.mp3

> dir *.mp3 /b > songlist.m3u

Comment: almost owns all the other answers. damn simple!

Answer (score 5):

You could also use Winamp. Just open the folder in the winamps' playlist and then save the result as an m3u file

Comment: And it's quite fast. It loads all metadata from my 3,5K collection in less than 10 minutes (300 files in 35 seconds on my PC, but YMMV), and after it is fully loaded you can save that playlist instantly.

Comment: I have about 12000 songs. It imports it into the media library in less than 10 minutes, loading the complete metadata.

Answer (score 4):

Try [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/)
it scans my entire 10000 song library in under 5 minutes.
And it runs faster and leaner than perhaps any audio player.

Do it the same way as in any other player --> Drag the entire folder into the main playlist and save it as one

Comment: Even if a .m3u could be made by coding it, it one of the fastest way on windows for new user ... (windows only I think)

Answer (score 2):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can do this. Drag the folder onto the window, then use the Playlist menu to export an m3u playlist.

Since you don't seem to want VLC, you could take a look at [tag (with the frontend)](http://members.home.nl/w.speek/tag.htm)

Comment: If I have say 300 folders, this can take a long time! I would love a batch job program though VLC is a great program!

Comment: If you want a playlist for each folder, then I found this solution to work: http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?s=86f542f40e9b067a616dbead252b9c25&showtopic=46167&view=findpost&p=408550

Answer (score 2):

[Mp3Tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) is focused on handling tags in bulk. Generation of a m3u playlist is one its basic features. It lets you do a lot of organization beyond that.

- It is quite fast
- Supports many formats: ID3v1, ID3v2.3, ID3v2.4, iTunes MP4, WMA, Vorbis Comments and APE Tags
- Is available for all flavors of Windows.

[image]